# How to optimize grouping of a DataFrame and performing operations on the groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, pandas-groupby

Here's an example of my dataframe:

```
d = {'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd'], \
     'round': [3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1], \
     'score': [0.3, 0.1, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.9, 0.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

```
    group   round   score
0   a          3    0.3
1   a          3    0.1
2   a          2    0.6
3   b          1    0.8
4   b          3    0.2
5   b          1    0.5
6   b          3    0.5
7   b          3    0.6
8   c          3    0.4
9   d          2    0.9
10  d          1    0.1
```

My actual dataframe has 6 columns and > 1,000,000 rows. I'm trying to figure out the fastest way to do the following:

For each group find the average of scores and perform some calculation with it for each of 3 rounds. If there are no scores, write 'NA'.

I'm not sure if it would be faster to make a list of lists and then convert it into a dataframe or make a new dataframe and populate that, so i went with the list first:

```
def test_df(data):
    value_counts = data['group'].value_counts().to_dict()
    avgs = []

    for key, val in value_counts.items():
        row = data[data['group'] == key]
        
        x = [key]
        
        if val < 2:
            x.extend([10 * row['score'].values[0] + 1 if i == row['round'].values[0] else 'NA' for i in range (1,4)])
        
        else:
            x.extend([(10 * row[row['round'] == i]['score'].mean() + 1) if len(row[row['round'] == i]) > 0 else 'NA' for i in range(1, 4)])
            
        avgs.append(x)     
            
    return avgs
```

Here I created a separate case because about 80% of groups in my data only have one row, so I figured it might speed things up maybe?

this returns the correct results in format `[group, round 1, round 2, round 3]`

```
[['b', 7.5, 'NA', 5.333333333333333],
 ['a', 'NA', 7.0, 3.0],
 ['d', 2.0, 10.0, 'NA'],
 ['c', 'NA', 'NA', 5.0]]
```

but it's looking like it's going to take a really really long time on the actual dataframe...
Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: 1) Have a look at `groupby` instead of using `for k, v in value_counts.items()`. 2) think how to do the operation across the groups/rounds: e.g. `data.groupby('group').transform('size')` puts the value count **of the group** on each row.

Comment: @QuangHoang yeah, i'm playing around the the group by multiple columns right now. Your piece of code gave me an error tho, `Transform function invalid for data types`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you're basically going a groupby/mean and a pivot.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd'], \
     'round': [3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1], \
     'score': [0.3, 0.1, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.9, 0.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = (df.groupby(['group','round'])['score'].mean()*10+1).reset_index()
df.pivot_table(index='group',columns='round',values='score', fill_value='NA').reset_index().values
```

Output

```
array([['a', 'NA', 7.0, 3.0],
       ['b', 7.5, 'NA', 5.333333333333333],
       ['c', 'NA', 'NA', 5.0],
       ['d', 2.0, 10.0, 'NA']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: That's pretty sharp reading +1. Also `df.pivot_table(index='group', columns='round', values='score') * 10 + 1`.

Comment: Wow, that is way simpler than what I was trying to do... Do you know if there's any way to implement a timer in there so I could keep track of the progress? I had a ```clear_output(wait = True)
 print(count)``` inside my for loop so i could see what row it was working on

Comment: oof, been running for 45 minutes and still not done :<

Answer (score 1):

The imbalanced dataset may show different results, but I tested with the blow scripts and found out even with the pandas dataframe, the result shows okay performance. However, you can always compare it with the native python data structure.

```
import random
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def generate_data():  # augmentation
    data = {'group': [], 'round': [], 'score': []}
    for index in range(10 ** 6):  # sample size
        data['group'].append(random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
        data['round'].append(random.randrange(1, 4))
        data['score'].append(round(random.random(), 1))
    return data

def calc_with_native_ds(data):  # native python data structure
    pass

def calc_with_pandas_df(df):  # pandas dataframe
    return df.groupby(['group', 'round']).mean()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = generate_data()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df.shape)

    start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

    # calc_with_native_ds(data)
    calc_with_pandas_df(df)

    end_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    elapsed_time = round((end_datetime - start_datetime).total_seconds(), 5)
    print(f"elapsed_time: {elapsed_time}")
```